# Does jacoco detect unused classes

Tags: java, code-coverage, jacoco

Jacoco, as all other profiling capabilities in java I know of, depends on java agents/instrumentation.

Java instrumentation can only impact bytecode when a class is loaded.

I wonder if it is somehow possible to detect unused classes with Jacoco? Obviously, there might be classes that are "dead" and are in turn, never loaded by the ClassLoader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When coverage output (HTML report, etc.) is generated after the test run has executed, JaCoCo scans additional classes in the runtime classpath that haven't been loaded during test execution, so they can also be instrumented and included in the output.

I implemented this same mechanism in my own code coverage tool (JMockit Coverage), which also relies on `java.lang.instrument`. It's the only way to have all relevant classes instrumented for coverage.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran a test: I created a file called Delete.java that is never called by any other method. The generated Jacoco report shows the Delete class with 0% coverage.

Comment: Thanks, @CMPS! Can you also explain how/why it happens?

Comment: When you generate a coverage report, you specify a classpath, and it reports on all classes based on the execution data file.  If there's a class in the JAR with no coverage, it is reported that way.  Note, if you don't specify a full classpath when generating the coverage report, then JaCoCo has no way of knowing that a class was not covered.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, though it might be easier to specify [`-verbose:class`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/clopts-139448.html#gbmtm) if you are not already using Jacoco.